# fontspec Error for some XeTeX/LuaTeX function

Tags: fontspec

I have a template I got from the internet. When I run it I get the following error.

```
! Fatal fontspec error: "not-pdftex"
! 
! Requires XeTeX or LuaTeX to function!
```

I have XeTeX and LuaTeX installed. It gives me an error at line 34 in fontspec.sty. 
Please help. I do not understand what is wrong. Thanks

Comment: How exactly do you try to compile it? Please post the used command line. Simply `latex myfile.txt` won't work here.

Comment: Have XeTeX or LuaTeX installed isn't sufficient, you must compile your document with Xe(La)TeX or Lua(La)TeX

Comment: Hmmm, I guess that error message could be rather more helpful.

Comment: @Matsaya: Could you please post your comment as an answer so that it can be accepted.

Comment: @Matsaya: Thanks. I was unaware of it. It works

Comment: @yO2gO Since Matsaya has answered your question, below, please consider marking the answer as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count. This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have XeTeX or LuaTeX installed isn't sufficient, you must compile your document with Xe(La)TeX or Lua(La)TeX.